# Changing parent screen behind a modal screen in react native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to change the screen which is behind the modal screen. I am using react navigation to show my screen as modal. Now on a button click i want to change the screen behind the modal screen due to the business logic.

I tried writing two navigations together but it only navigated my modal screen twice.
The first time it navigated inside the modal and second time it goes full screen.I want to keep my modal screen as it is and change the screen behind screen so if some one pulls down the modal screen the person would see the changed screen now.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.